# How did Thor get treasury to purchase resources to rebuild Asgard on Earth?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel

When Donald Blake awakened Thor from the "Void of Non-Existence", the Asgard was already destroyed by the Loki's Army. From where did Thor get the money required to purchase resources to rebuild Asgard on Earth? As Blake, Thor was merely a Doctor who can't have that amount of money to build an entire city.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He didn't rebuild the city with conventional supplies. Instead he used magic to call the city forth. In general, normal stone and lumber don't float above the ground. While they glance over it in the first few issues of Thor, in Iron Man you see him process a bunch of reports about the "city just appearing".

**EDIT**

Since Thor can call forth stone and wood, there is no reason to suppose that he couldn't call forth a bag or ten of gold when he chooses.

Comment: The city wasn't in a pocket dimension. It was in ours and well on the land of USA. How do you suppose to get a big piece of land free of cost?

Comment: he paid with a bag of gold. He handed it directly to the farmer whose land he bought. It was in issue #2, I'm pretty sure

Comment: @sarge_smith More precisely, he showed the farmer one of the gold vaults, told him to take however much he felt was a fair price and then get the hell out.

Answer (score 0):

He used a large portion of the Odin force (or Thor Force considering he was the All Father at the time) to bring the castle back. The individual Asguardians were kept in the body's of people in Earth.